# CSS - I can't get a simple Slick Carousel to work

Tags: css, slick.js

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title>My Now Amazing Webpage</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick-theme.css"/>
  </head>
  <style>
    .d1 {
      background-color: lightblue;
      display: flex;
    }
    a {
      background-color: yellow;
      display: block;
      margin: 0 10px;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
    }
  </style>
  <body>

  <div class="d1">
    <div><a href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/">1</a></div>
    <div><a href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/">2</a></div>
    <div><a href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/">3</a></div>
    <div><a href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/">4</a></div>
    <div><a href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/">5</a></div>
    <div><a href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/">6</a></div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.multiple-items').slick({
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3
      });
    });
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to display 6 `<a>`'s in a row with 3 to be shown at a time. I use the above code copied and pasted directly from their tutorial site (https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) and I replace the container (class d1) as well as the child elements but the result does not function or move at all, not even the left and right buttons appear... The folder contains only this .html file.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things I changed to fix this:

1. Add the slick initialisation class "multiple-items"; this tells Slick what container to affect
2. Link to slick css, theme css and javascript repos on cdn; make sure you are linking to those properly in your project (not the cdn versions I'd say)

Your code, updated, now works:

```css
.d1 .slick-prev,
.d1 .slick-next {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
z-index: 9999;
opacity: 1;
}

.d1 .slick-prev {
left: 25px;
}

.d1 .slick-next {
right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <title>My Now Amazing Webpage</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.css"/>
  </head>
  <style>
    .d1 {
      background-color: lightblue;
      display: flex;
    }
    a {
      background-color: yellow;
      display: block;
      margin: 0 10px;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
    }
  </style>
  <body>

  <div class="multiple-items d1">
    <div><a href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/">1</a></div>
    <div><a href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/">2</a></div>
    <div><a href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/">3</a></div>
    <div><a href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/">4</a></div>
    <div><a href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/">5</a></div>
    <div><a href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/">6</a></div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.multiple-items').slick({
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3, 
        arrows: true
      });
    });
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @darkchampionz check your broken links by inspecting your code and fixing the errors in the console. Depending on your set up it's possible you need all your code to be local.

Comment: Fixed some broken links, my bad. Seems to work now but one last thing could be: why are the left and right buttons not visible? Any way to fix this? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @darkchampionz I've styled the arrows to show, the rest is up to you. :) You'll need to put your override classes after the slick css styling in load order. Please vote this up if you like the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are initializing a class "d1" for slick. But on scripts you are targeting the wrong class. Please update your script with the following

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      // Your class "multiple-items" will replace with "d1"
      $('.d1').slick({
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to replace .multiple-items with d1 which is your class name in your jQuery. 
Also make sure, your cdn or path to the file directory is correct. 
Any console error?

Comment: Please post your codefix here, your answer is only a comment at the moment.